# Error installing Karma on Node - error retrieving current directory - on OSX

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, karma-runner

I've been struggling with this one today, and can't figure out what the problem is - and unfortunately Google hasn't been much help.

I'm trying to follow the AngularJS tutorial but am unable to install Karma. Every time I try I get an error saying "Error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied".

Here's a copy of the output in bash:

```
Barts-MacBook-Pro:~ bart$ sudo npm install -g karma
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-0.8.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-0.8.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlbuilder/0.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/LiveScript/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dateformat/1.0.2-1.2.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul/0.1.22
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/growly
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlbuilder/0.4.2
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/-/optimist-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-0.6.0-1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/LiveScript/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dateformat/1.0.2-1.2.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-0.6.0-1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/growly
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul/0.1.22
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.12.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/-/optimist-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.12.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/-/http-proxy-0.10.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q/-/q-0.9.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/-/http-proxy-0.10.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/q/-/q-0.9.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prelude-ls
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/1.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fileset
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prelude-ls
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/1.0.3
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.15.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fileset
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-1.2.5.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.15.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen/-/escodegen-0.0.21.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-1.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen/-/escodegen-0.0.21.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/estraverse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/estraverse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander

> ws@0.4.25 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
/usr/local/bin/karma -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma
karma@0.8.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
├── pause@0.0.1
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── xmlbuilder@0.4.2
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── chokidar@0.6.2
├── growly@1.1.1
├── mime@1.2.9
├── q@0.9.3
├── coffee-script@1.6.2
├── lodash@1.1.1
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.0)
├── rimraf@2.1.4 (graceful-fs@1.2.0)
├── optimist@0.3.5 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
├── LiveScript@1.0.1 (prelude-ls@0.6.0)
├── minimatch@0.2.12 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.3.0)
├── log4js@0.6.3 (dequeue@1.0.3, semver@1.1.4, async@0.1.15, readable-stream@1.0.2)
├── http-proxy@0.10.2 (pkginfo@0.2.3, utile@0.1.7)
├── istanbul@0.1.22 (abbrev@1.0.4, which@1.0.5, fileset@0.1.5, nopt@2.0.0, wordwrap@0.0.2, async@0.1.22, mkdirp@0.3.5, esprima@0.9.9, handlebars@1.0.10, escodegen@0.0.21)
└── socket.io@0.9.14 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.11)
Barts-MacBook-Pro:~ bart$
```

I'm running Node 0.10.4, btw.

Unfortunately I'm now at a bit of a loss so any assistance would be gratefully received!

Many thanks,

Bart

**EDIT - Jan 2017**

I originally asked this question w.r.t. OSX Mountain Lion, but I've run into similar issues on newer versions of OSX as well. I've edited my answer below to include what I think is a better solution for *all* versions of OSX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so I dug into this a little further, and tried the following:

```
sudo npm install -g ws
```

This is the package that's actually failing to install. From there Googling found this, on StackOverflow: [Trouble installing tower module - ws module crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442249/trouble-installing-tower-module-ws-module-crashes). This lead me to the instructions to enable the root account on my Macbook Pro: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528.

Once I'd done that I could now execute the following in bash to successfully install karma:

```
su
npm install -g karma
```

And that's it! Hope this helps anyone else who runs into a similar problem.

**EDIT - Jan 2017 - A better solution**

To avoid the whole drama of having to install global modules using sudo on OSX, which can lead to weird problems such as getcwd() failing due to lack of permissions, I'd strongly recommend installing node using nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm. This also has the advantage that you can also use multiple versions of node on the same machine.